# Python list indexing

Tags: python, list, indexing

Im sure this is a repeated question, however I have no idea how to phrase it.
What does pythons[1:3] yield?

```
pythons = [’Graham’, ’Eric’, ’Terry’, ’John’, ’Michael’, ’Terry’]
```

I know now the answer is Eric and Terry, but why?

Comment: well if your so sure that this is a duplicate why didn't you do your research....

Comment: @KDawG:  It is difficult to search for slice notation when you don't know it's called slice notation.

Comment: Indiana University's crappy Intro to Programing class.

Answer (score 5):

Think about it like this:

```
    #0       #1       #2      #3        #4        #5
[’Graham’, ’Eric’, ’Terry’, ’John’, ’Michael’, ’Terry’]
```

As it was pointed out above, we start counting at 0 in python, and our ranges are not inclusive on the top end. So, when we say [1:3], we are saying "Grab all of the elements in this list from indexes in the range (1,3). So we split up the list like this

```
          |                 |    
    #0    |   #1       #2   |   #3        #4        #5
[’Graham’,| ’Eric’, ’Terry’,| ’John’, ’Michael’, ’Terry’]
          |                 |
```

So, a new list, `['Eric', 'Terry']` is returned. This same principle applies with strings too.

Answer (score 1):

List are ordered according to data entry, every time you append something this will be the last item of the list:

```
>>>pythons.append('Monty')
>>>pythons
['Graham', 'Eric', 'Terry', 'John', 'Michael', 'Terry', 'Monty']
```

indexes starts from 0 and you can imagine the index number between the elements:

```
['Graham', 'Eric', 'Terry', 'John', 'Michael', 'Terry', 'Monty']
0        1       2        3       4          5        6
```

So pythons[1:3] select the elements **between** 1 and 3, Eric and the first Terry.

pythons[3] select the **element that start from** 3

[Python Lists tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

Answer (score 0):

`pythons[1:3]` yields `Eric, Terry` because

1 brings back the 2nd element in the list, because you start counting at 0. And 3 is the highest limit of the range, but is not inclusive so it brings back 2. That is why you get `Eric, Terry`.